# Dealing with timeouts in Sauce Labs

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, saucelabs

I have Web Driver code that works without issue when running on a local instance of a browser. My code interacts with the browser, but has a period where it kicks off some background tasks via terminal in order to set up data for the remainder of the test. This is an end to end test and it needs to execute in this order, leaving the browser idle for a short period of time, usually under 5 minutes. After the background tasks complete, the browser is then again interacted with.

Unfortunately when I run my rests remotely from Sauce Labs, when running the background tasks Sauce Labs finds the browser as being inactive for longer than 90 seconds and assumes there is an issue. This results in a failure even though the test never fails. I can't seem to find anything in the documentation regarding how to increase the idle timeout. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide some of your selenium code? `WebDriver` initialization, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saucelabs has a few different types of timeouts:

- Max test duration
- Command timeout
- Idle test timeout

More info: https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Test+Configuration+Options#TestConfigurationOptions-Timeouts

Either the max duration or idle timeout should help you out. I think the idle time still burns down sauce test minutes though.

Answer (score 1):

when you set up your desired_capabilities add:

```
desired_capabilities["idle-timeout"] = "180"
```

I did 180 seconds here, but you can do whatever...